# Can't define OpenCms version

Tags: java, content-management-system, web, opencms

How can I check what OpenCms version is used? I've got only the access to the web site source files. I haven't access to a web server and a database. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web site source files, if you're talking about the expanded war file, there is a folder  named 'setup' and under it a file named 'versions.txt'. In there, you see the OpenCms version number.

Comment: what do you mean with "website source code" ? All files of OpenCms are stored in it's VFS (virtual file system), which is usually a mysql database. There are no files on the real file system, only the OpenCms framework files themselves. Even then, if you don't have a war file, I assume you are talking about the expanded files that initially came from the war file. There should also be a setup folder then. Please let me know what exactly you mean with 'website source code'.

Comment: I've only got java files and openCms synchronized files

Comment: Also I've got access to the remote openCms web gui, but I must work locally, so I should expand my own openCms and java source on my machine.

Comment: If you have access to the OpenCms Web GUI, then you find the version number on the OpenCms workplace login page. It's on that page. Usually http://<domain>/opencms/opencms/system/login or similar, depending on your servlet mapping and context name.

Comment: Do you mean you need to work with the OpenCms core code and deploy your customized opencms.jar, without even having access to the entire system? That sounds like a weird construct and hard task to manage... good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I 've checked the version and I must install the project on my local machine and I really don't know how to do that

Comment: Websites in OpenCms are usually packaged as modules, inside OpenCms. You can usually go into the Web UI / Administration / Module Management and export the website as a module, if it has been setup as a module properly. Then, you'd install OpenCms locally (you don't need the OpenCms sources, just the 'binary' version of it), run the setup. Then import the website module from the live server to your local OpenCms (also via Web UI, Admin, Module Management).